# GCP deploy instance fails from ansible script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine, quota

I've been deploying clusters in GCP via ansible scripts for more then a year now, but all of a sudden one of my scripts keeps giving me this error:

> libcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: u\"The zone 'projects/[project]/zones/europe-west1-d' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.

The obvious reason would be that I don't have enough resources, but not a whole lot has changed and quotas look good:
[image: quotas]

The ansible script itself doesn't ask for a lot.
I'm creating 3 instances of n1-standard-4 with 100GB SSD.
See snippet of script below:

```
tasks:
    - name: create boot disks
      gce_pd:
          disk_type: pd-ssd
          image: "debian-9-stretch-v20171025"
          name: "{{ item.node }}-disk"
          size_gb: 100
          state: present
          zone: "europe-west1-d"
          service_account_email: "{{ service_account_email }}"          
          credentials_file: "{{ credentials_file }}"
          project_id: "{{ project_id }}"          
      with_items: "{{nodes}}"
      async: 3600
      poll: 2

    - name: create instances
      gce:        
        instance_names: "{{item.node}}"
        zone: "europe-west1-d"
        machine_type: "n1-standard-4"        
        preemptible: "{{ false if item.num == '0' else true }}"        
        disk_auto_delete: true
        disks:
          - name: "{{ item.node }}-disk"
            mode: READ_WRITE
        state: present
        service_account_email: "{{ service_account_email }}"
        service_account_permissions: "compute-rw"
        credentials_file: "{{ credentials_file }}"
        project_id: "{{ project_id }}"
        tags: "elasticsearch"        
      register: gce_raw_results
      with_items: "{{nodes}}"
      async: 3600
      poll: 2
```

**Update 1:**

- The service account is editor of the entire project. So right issue seems unlikely.
- It started happening March 24 2018. And every night since then. So if it's a 'out of stock' issue that would be very coincidental, right?
  Besides I have been running this script the entire day so far and it fails most of the time (see below for success).
- I've tested a few times and it might have something to do with the 'preemptible' flag on the instance. (I start 3 nodes, but at least the first has to stay up to at least work) => `preemptible: "{{ false if item.num == '0' else true }}"`
  If I turn off preemptible (false) then it runs without a hitch.
  The 'workaround' seems to be just don't use preemptible instances, but this used to work for a year without failing once. Did something change?
  Did GCP's API change? Did ansible gce not implement these changes?

---

The full error is:

> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [create boot disks]
>   **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** changed: [localhost] => (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-0',
>   u'ip_field': u'private_ip', u'zone': u'europe-west1-d',
>   u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch-link', u'num': u'0', u'machine_type':
>   u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id': u'[projectid]'}) changed: [localhost]
>   => (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-1', u'ip_field': u'private_ip', u'zone': u'europe-west1-d', u'cluster_name':
>   u'elasticsearch-link', u'num': u'1', u'machine_type':
>   u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id': u'[projectid]'}) ok: [localhost] =>
>   (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-2', u'ip_field': u'private_ip',
>   u'zone': u'europe-west1-d', u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch-link',
>   u'num': u'2', u'machine_type': u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id':
>   u'[projectid]'})
>
> TASK [create instances]
>   ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** changed: [localhost] => (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-0',
>   u'ip_field': u'private_ip', u'zone': u'europe-west1-d',
>   u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch-link', u'num': u'0', u'machine_type':
>   u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id': u'[projectid]'}) changed: [localhost]
>   => (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-1', u'ip_field': u'private_ip', u'zone': u'europe-west1-d', u'cluster_name':
>   u'elasticsearch-link', u'num': u'1', u'machine_type':
>   u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id': u'[projectid]'}) failed: [localhost]
>   (item={u'node': u'elasticsearch-link-2', u'ip_field': u'private_ip',
>   u'zone': u'europe-west1-d', u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch-link',
>   u'num': u'2', u'machine_type': u'n1-standard-4', u'project_id':
>   u'[projectid]'}) =>  {"ansible_job_id": "371957735383.2688",
>   "changed": false, "cmd":
>   "/tmp/.ansible-airflow/ansible-tmp-1522742180.0-71790706749341/gce.py",
>   "data": "", "failed": 1, "finished": 1, "item": {"cluster_name":
>   "elasticsearch-link", "ip_field": "private_ip",  "machine_type":
>   "n1-standard-4", "node": "elasticsearch-link-2", "num": "2",
>   "project_id": "[projectid]", "zone": "europe-west1-d"}, "msg":
>   "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \"/tmp/.ansible-airflow/ansible-tmp-1522742180.0-71790706749341/async_wrapper.py\",
>   line 158, in _run_module\n    (filtered_outdata, json_warnings) =
>   _filter_non_json_lines(outdata)\n  File \"/tmp/.ansible-airflow/ansible-tmp-1522742180.0-71790706749341/async_wrapper.py\",
>   line 99, in _filter_non_json_lines\n    raise ValueError('No start of
>   json char found')\nValueError: No start of json char found\n",
>   "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line 750, in \n
>   main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line
>   712, in main\n    module, gce, inames, number)\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line 524, in
>   create_instances\n    instance, lc_machine_type, lc_image(),
>   **gce_args\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py\",
>   line 3874, in create_node\n   self.connection.async_request(request,
>   method='POST', data=node_data)\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 784, in async_request\n    response = request(**kwargs)\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py\",
>   line 121, in request\n   response = super(GCEConnection,
>   self).request(*args, **kwargs)\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py\",
>   line 806, in request\n    *args, **kwargs)\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 641, in request\n    response = responseCls(**kwargs)\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 163, in **init**\n    self.object = self.parse_body()\n  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py\",
>   line 268, in parse_body\n    raise GoogleBaseError(message,
>   self.status, code)\nlibcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: u\"The
>   zone 'projects/[projectid]/zones/europe-west1-d' does not have enough
>   resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or
>   try again later.\"\n", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call
>   last):", "  File \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line
>   750, in ", "    main()", "  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line 712, in main", "
>   module, gce, inames, number)", "  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_OnIK1e/ansible_module_gce.py\", line 524, in
>   create_instances", "    instance, lc_machine_type, lc_image(),
>   **gce_args", "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py\",
>   line 3874, in create_node", "
>   self.connection.async_request(request, method='POST',
>   data=node_data)", "  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 784, in async_request", "    response = request(**kwargs)", " 
>   File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py\",
>   line 121, in request", "    response = super(GCEConnection,
>   self).request(*args, **kwargs)", "  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py\",
>   line 806, in request", "    *args, **kwargs)", "  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 641, in request", "    response = responseCls(**kwargs)", "  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py\",
>   line 163, in **init**", "    self.object = self.parse_body()", "  File
>   \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/google.py\",
>   line 268, in parse_body", "    raise GoogleBaseError(message,
>   self.status, code)", "libcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: u\"The
>   zone 'projects/[projectid]/zones/europe-west1-d' does not have enough
>   resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or
>   try again later.\""]}
>           to retry, use: --limit @/usr/local/airflow/ansible/playbooks/elasticsearch-link-cluster-create.retry

Comment: There may be a temporary stockout for that zone on one of the resources you request. As stated by the error message, you can either try in another zone or try again later.

Comment: Well it happens every night since last week or so. So it seems persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is not showing that is an error with the quota, but rather an issue with the zone resources, I would advise you to try a new zone.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas):

> Even if you have a regional quota, it is possible that a resource might not be available in a specific zone. For example, you might have quota in region us-central1 to create VM instances, but might not be able to create VM instances in the zone us-central1-a if the zone is depleted. In such cases, try creating the same resource in another zone, such as us-central1-f.

Therefore when creating the script you should take this possibility into account even if it is not so common.

This issue is even more highlithed in case of [preentible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) instances since:

> Preemptible instances are finite Compute Engine resources, so they might not always be available. [...] these instances if it requires access to those resources for other tasks. Preemptible instances are excess Compute Engine capacity so their availability varies with usage.

**UPDATE**

To doublecheck what I am saying you can try to keep the preentible flag and change the zone to be sure the script it is working properly and it is a stockout happening during the evening (and since during the day it works this should be the case).

- If the issue it is really the availability -| you might consider to spin up preentible instance and if not available, catch the error and then either rely on normal one or on a different zone |-

### UPDATE2

As I promised I created on your behalf the feature request, you can follow the updates on the public  tracker.
I advise you to start it in order to receive the updates on the email:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/77734062

Comment: So this was the solution. I changed to europe-west1-c and everything worked again. If feels a bit fragile to just 'try' some zones until one succeeds. 
Is there a way to either ask GCP to pick any zone within a region or pre query the state, so I can pick the zone with most change of success?
The reason is that spinning up the machines is an important part of our data pipeline.

Comment: No it is not available, but actually it could be useful, I will open a feature request on your behalf and I will update the answer with the public link which you can star in order to get notifications (disclaimer I am part of Google Cloud Platform Support)

Comment: @TomLous I have updated the answer with the feature request as promised.